# does anyone know where the source of this gemora:

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara

Does anyone know where the source of this gemora: 
A father says my son should be for a korban, and the gemora digresses and says we dont know if the father is a chosid or a shoteh.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second part? What does the father say?

Comment: i cant remember exactly, but something along the lines of a korban -sacrifice.

Comment: Thinking of Yiftach pledging (his daughter)?

Comment: no, not yiftach

Comment: A quick search on sefaria.org for "חסיד שוטה קרבן" returned zero results. "חסיד קרבן" brought no relevant results.